# Akka http request is not consumed with runFold when it's piped to actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

My code is based on examples in Akka documentation, so it should work as charm, but problem is that I only receive headers of the response, content length, and when it comes to folding body I get:

> [INFO] [08/17/2016 13:01:21.116] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka://default/user/$a] Length: 29407
>
> [INFO] [08/17/2016 13:01:21.127] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka://default/user/$a] Got response, body: List()

Actor code:

```
class AkkaHttp extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import context.dispatcher

  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))

  val http = Http(context.system)

  override def preStart() = {
    http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io/"))
      .pipeTo(self)
  }

  def receive = {
    case s: String => {
      log.info(s)
    }
    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) => {
      log.info("Length: " + entity.contentLengthOption.getOrElse("No content"))
      log.info("Got response, body: " + entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty) {
        case (acc, b) => acc ++ b }.map(s => s.utf8String))
    }
    case HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
  }

}
```

If I change preStart() method to fold response in it and send just String, the body of page is logged:

```
  override def preStart() = {
    val httpRequest: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io/")
    val request = http.singleRequest(httpRequest)
    request.flatMap { response =>
      response.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty) { 
          case (acc, b) => acc ++ b }.map(f => f.utf8String)
    }
    .pipeTo(self)
  }
```

What could be a reason that response entity is not folded in first version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of that `runFold` is another `Future`.  You then go and try and print that `Future`, which won't yield anything of value as it's a `Future` and not the underlying `String` that you want.  If you change the case in your `receive` to this, then it should start working:

```
case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) => 
  log.info("Length: " + entity.contentLengthOption.getOrElse("No content"))

  val entityFut = 
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty) {
      case (acc, b) => acc ++ b 
    }.
    map(s => s.utf8String)
  entityFut pipeTo self
```

Comment: Thanks! But as I want to have it logged under `case HttpResponse(...)` I think best will be to use `entityFut.onComplete(f => log.info("With onComplete: " + f.getOrElse("")))` as it is non blocking?

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing in that callback.  If you are just logging then sure, that can work...